# 'java.lang.AbstractMethodError' when initializing the Chrome driver and Firefox driver in Selenium

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, abstractmethoderror

I am getting the below error when initializing the Chrome driver and Firefox driver in Selenium.

### Initializing the Chrome Driver

> java.lang.AbstractMethodError: Receiver class
> org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriverService$Builder does not define
> or inherit an implementation of the resolved method 'abstract void
> loadSystemProperties()' of abstract class
> org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverService$Builder.

### Initializing the Firefox Driver

> java.lang.AbstractMethodError: Receiver class
> org.openqa.selenium.firefox.GeckoDriverService$Builder does not define
> or inherit an implementation of the resolved method 'abstract void
> loadSystemProperties()' of abstract class
> org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverService$Builder.

My code is below. In below code I have tried only for the Chrome and Firefox browsers.

I have tried with use of the WebDriver Manager as well as without the WebDriver Manager for the Chrome Driver initialization (As commented in the below code). For both these scenarios this error message is visible.

I have executed the same code 2 months back and it was working fine. But suddenly from yesterday I was facing this issue and up to now could not identify the root cause for this issue.

```
public static WebDriver initialization() {

    if (driver == null) {

        switch (propertyBrowserValue) {
            case "chrome":
               // System.setProperty(getPropertyInitializeValue(initFilePath, "chromeDriverName"), getPropertyInitializeValue(initFilePath, "chromeDriverPath"));

              //  ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
              //  options.addArguments("--remote-allow-origins=*");
              //  driver = new ChromeDriver(options);

                WebDriverManager.chromedriver().setup();
                driver = new ChromeDriver();
                break;

            case "firefox":
                WebDriverManager.firefoxdriver().setup();
                driver = new FirefoxDriver();
                break;

            case "IE":
                WebDriverManager.iedriver().setup();
                driver = new InternetExplorerDriver();
                break;

            case "Edge":
                WebDriverManager.edgedriver().setup();
                driver = new EdgeDriver();
                break;

            default:
                System.out.println("You have not setup a correct browser "
                        + "type in configuration file");
        }


    }

    driver.manage().deleteAllCookies();
    driver.manage().window().maximize();
    return driver;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of setup() can you try with this,

```
driver = WebDriverManager.chromedriver().create();
```

Comment: Even with this change I am getting the error: (Part of the error is extracted here)

Caused by: java.lang.AbstractMethodError: Receiver class org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriverService$Builder does not define or inherit an implementation of the resolved method 'abstract void loadSystemProperties()' of abstract class org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverService$Builder.
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverService$Builder.build(DriverService.java:496)
    at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriverService.createDefaultService(ChromeDriverService.java:146)